# How to make "hanging" clothes react correctly with the body movement

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

I'm having a problem with rigging a skirt and a cape.

[image: Skirt Normal]

As you can see, this is the skirt without any movement.
[image: Skirt Deformed]

But once I move the leg a little, the skirt not only will deform horribly, but also moves when the leg hasn't touched it yet. (You can see how the leg was moved just a little and the skirt already detected as if the leg were next to it)

[image: Skirt Cube]

I searched some tutorials to try to fix it and found one where it said that with a cube subdivided by 10, then parented with the armature with automatic weights and then use the mesh deform modifier in the skirt will fix the problem, but as you can see, the problem is still there.
[image: Cape]

[image: Cape 2]

So while looking for tutorials I tried to rig the costume I made to continue with the project while I find a solution, but I have almost the same problem with the cape for being hanging instead of being stick to the body (like the gloves and shirt)

**Is there a way to rig the skirt perfectly that I haven't discovered yet? And a way to avoid the mesh merging inside themselves? (Like it happens with the cape)**

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: @Chris Added the blend file

Comment: ok, just by looking at it for 1 minute: your face orientation of the whole character is wrong:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHML5.png

Comment: and question: how shall the witch skirt move at all? there is no modifier and no armature for it....did you delete too much of your uploaded file?

Comment: is there a special reason why you did set "normals flip" in all your solidify modfiers?

Comment: @Chris That's because the solidify modifier that I have active as the outliner, if I deactivate the solidify modifier, it is okay
https://ibb.co/1s2KVwv

Comment: About the witch skirt, since the normal one was giving me problems, I haven't parented that one yet, since I think it will have the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the position of the modifiers. I had the armature modifier in the third position (subdivision and solidify before it) so once I put the armature modifier first, the skirt deforms perfectly (also with some bones added to manually change some parts)[image: Sit]

This also fixed some problems I had with some clothes that didn't move correctly as the body moved.